# remove "<" and ">" tags from an array in php

Tags: php, string

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "<one@one.com>"
    [1] => "<two@two.co.in>"
    [2] => "<three@hello.co.in>"
)
```

Now I want to remove `"<"` and `">"` from above array so that it look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => "one@one.com"
    [1] => "two@two.co.in"
    [2] => "three@hello.co.in"
)
```

How to do this in php? Please help me out.

I'm using `array_filter()`; is there any easier way to do that except `array_filter()`?

Comment: Uhmmm... what do you want to remove from the first array? To me it's empty...

Comment: Never mind. Pekka just edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take an array_walk on it:

```
// Removes starting and trailing < and > characters

 function trim_gt_and_lt(&$value) 
{ 
    $value = trim($value, "<>"); 
}

array_walk($array, 'trim_gt_and_lt');
```

Note however that this will **also** remove starting `>` and trailing `<` which may not be what you want.

Comment: This also will strip leading > and trailing <. Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: You could probably even do it with an anonymous function in array_walk(), but I can't do the looking  up and testing right now.

Comment: @cletus, good point. I assume in his data set it's irrelevant but still. +1 to your solution and added a caveat to mine.

Comment: Actually, maybe you could use `str_replace` instead of `trim`, just in case the brackets could be somewhere else (not that I really believe that)...

Comment: Its an important caveat but honestly I didn't even know you could do that with `trim()` so +1 for that.

Comment: It is not working Dear.....
it does not strip even a single tag..
may be i m wrong or u didn't understand my problem

Comment: Works perfectly for me, strips every occurrence of `<` and `>` from the array.

Comment: @Franz str_replace would do this. I have posted my reply which shows how to do this using str_replace

Comment: I know it does. That's why I mentioned it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, if you want to change values it's [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) you want, not [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). `array_filter()` selectively removes or keeps array entries.

```
$output = array_map('remove_slashes', $input);

function remove_slashes($s) {
  return preg_replace('!(^<|>$)!', '', $s);
}
```

You could of course do this with a simple `foreach` loop too.

Comment: Aint these called *angle brackets*?

Answer (score 1):

[str_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is an option, or any other replacement functions in PHP like preg_replace etc.

Answer (score 0):

you go through the array and do it one by one?

```
$arr = array( "<one@one.com>", "<two@two.co.in>" ,"<three@hello.co.in>");
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){
    $arr[$k] = trim($v,"<>") ;
}
print_r($arr);
```

output

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => one@one.com
    [1] => two@two.co.in
    [2] => three@hello.co.in
)
```

Comment: have u apply this function or just wrire the output what i want

Comment: what do you mean? as you can see from my output, it does what you want

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$teste = array("<one@one.com>","<two@two.co.in>","<three@hello.co.in>");
var_dump(str_replace(array('<','>'),'',$teste));
```

Will print out

```
array
  0 => string 'one@one.com' (length=11)
  1 => string 'two@two.co.in' (length=13)
  2 => string 'three@hello.co.in' (length=17)
```