# jsonp -> json_decode()

Tags: php, json, jsonp

for some reason I can't get the information out of a returned jsonp string,

```
<?php
// Created by Talisman 01/2010 ★✩ 

$vorto = $_GET['vorto']; // Get the Word from Outer Space and Search for it!

if (isset($vorto))
 {
 echo $vorto;
 } else {
  $Help = "No Vorto -> add ?vorto=TheWordYouWant to the end of this website";
  echo $Help;
 }



// Now Lets Search Alex's Vortaro, It uses jsonp
// ex. http://vortaro.us.to/ajax/epo/eng/petas/?callback=?
// Future Feature inproved language functinality

$AVurl1 = "http://vortaro.us.to/ajax/epo/eng/"; 
$AVurl2 = "/?callback=";
$AVfinalurl= $AVurl1 . $vorto . $AVurl2;

echo $AVfinalurl . ' </br> '; // DEBUG CODE 

$AVcontent = file_get_contents($AVfinalurl) ;
echo $AVcontent . ' </br> ';   // DEBUG CODE
```

// ★✩  Why does this next line not work?

```
 $AVDecode = json_decode($AVcontent);


// /* 
  if(isset( $AVcontent)) {          // DEBUG CODE
  echo "json_decode set AVcontent" . ' </br> ';
  } else {
  echo "something fishy here" . ' </br> ';
  }

 if (empty($AVcontent)){
  echo "EMPTY EMPTY" . ' </br> ';
  } else {
  echo "Not Empty". ' </br> ';
  }

echo $AVDecode . ' </br> ';
// */

// Why can't I echo or access information with $AVDecode? Is it something with
// jsonp?

?>
```

this is my results

> komputilojhttp://vortaro.us.to/ajax/epo/eng/komputiloj/?callback=
>
> ({"text":"komputilo: computer"})
>
> json_decode set AVcontent
>
> Not Empty

I should be seeing the echo $AVDecode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Debugging suggestion:**

Check the output of [**json_last_error()**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). It should give you an exact reason why it doesn't work. Available from PHP 5.3.0 only, though.

**The reason:**

[**JSONP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is not identical with [**JSON**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). It contains extra data that breaks json_decode().

**Solution:**

Remove the extra brackets using `substr($AVDecode, 1, strlen($AVDecode)-2)`

Comment: I got this Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_last_error() in /Users/briancarpenter/Sites/Vortoj/preniVortoj.php on line 53 with echo json_last_error()

Comment: Oh, its > 5.3.0 only. You probably have an older PHP version. Hang on, I'll run it. Can you point out exaclty what you get from the data source?

Comment: Decoding: ({"text":"<b>peti</b>: ask, ask for, beg, bid, request"}) works for me *if I remove the surrounding brackets* `()`. json_decode can't handle jsonp. You need to either remove the brackets manually, or (better) make your data source output proper json.

Comment: Its a dictionary Esperanto to English translation,  can I search for and remove these ()  there has got to be a way. Another site uses it like this http://libraro.co.cc/

Comment: +1.  JSONP is JSON with a function wrapper around it.  You could remove the function wrapper using the substr function, then evaluate the remaining JSON statement.

Comment: @Klanestro: Yes, it's possible no problem. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093420/remove-and-tags-from-an-array-in-php/2093452#2093452 and replace `<>` by `()`.

Comment: Or use substr() as Andy E suggests. It's fine in this case.

Comment: You need to clean every JSONP request you make. You can use `substr($AVDecode, 1, strlen($AVDecode)-2)`

Comment: @Pekka웃 [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) isn't PHP 5.3+ only. PHP.net says 5.0+.

Comment: @kaiser it's showing `> 5.3.0` for me, which language version are you viewing?

Comment: @Pekka웃 de_DE/German, but I just re-read and saw that I misread that _facepalm_ ... `PHP 5 >= 5.3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant echo an object or an array.
please tell us what this line prints out:

```
print_r(json_decode($AVcontent));
```

place it right after the   `$AVDecode = json_decode($AVcontent);`

Comment: Absolutly nothing happens, no change 
print_r(json_decode($AVcontent));
does nothing,

Comment: maybe thats ({"text":"komputilo: computer"}) an invalid json string http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: no komputilo is the $vorto = $_GET['vorto'] that the page starts out with.

Answer (score 0):

Your example URL returns

```
?({"text":"<b>peti</b>: ask, ask for, beg, bid, request"})
```

JSONP is not valid JSON, it will wrap it into your supplied callback like

```
callbackname(JSONIsInHere)
```

So you need to substring $AVcontent from the first occurrence of ( to the the last ocurrence of ) so that you will get the callback parameter which is valid JSON and can be encoded with json_decode.