# Iterate over a JSON response and get results into variables

Tags: php, json

I am trying to build a simple script that I can pass in a list of Twitter username and it will then access the Twitter API and returns a list of details for the user's that I requested.

Below is what I have so far, it returns a JSON response with all the data for the 3 user's that I sent in the URL.

I need to figure out how to access each of these items, I plan to save them to a database so I need to be able to access the returned items as a variable.  Also the number of users/results in the JSON will be different each time depending on how many names I request so I need to somehow iterate over this JSON response.

Can anyone help me?

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=fishriver,metinogtem,friendproject');

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($obj);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `foreach` to iterate over the JSON object.

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=fishriver,metinogtem,friendproject');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($obj as $index => $user) {
        echo $user->screen_name."<br>";
        // insert into database here
    }
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Great now combine this answer in case your json is jsonp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101316/jsonp-json-decode

Answer (score 4):

Iterating is easy:

```
foreach ($obj as $varName => $varValue)
{
   // ...
}
```